# YouTube Background Video doesn't expand vertically

Tags: css, video, youtube

I want to use a YouTube video as background video. However the video doesn't expand vertically. Does anyone know how to fix this?
Also, there is a lag when the video ends (looping) any thoughts?
When I load the video from my server it works perfectly

```
<video class="bg-video__main" playsinline="" autoplay="" muted="" loop="">
<source src="img/cover-video.m4v" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

But it doesn't when I use it bring it from YouTube

```
<iframe class="bg-video__main" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/u7vq7nImkV8?controls=0&showinfo=0&rel=0&autoplay=1&loop=1&list=PLMGGIV_q_unoMJGsH4GnoBv2dLkCxdb6D" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

http://freewill-freespace.com/test

I need to loaded from a external server because the video is around 5mb.[YouTube background video issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gXLQ5.jpg)

Comment: So are you just trying to maintain the aspect ratio of the video?

Comment: yes, to expand the video vertically.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `width="100%"` for horizontal expansion and `height="100%"` for vertical into your iframe.

For looping, it seems that you already did it by adding `loop=1` in your url. It is not compatible with all players through. If you want more information about this, you can see the [google documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#loop)

Comment: Would that be a playlist of 2 (duplicate) items playing on repeat (giving effect of one/same video looping)?

Comment: You can do that for tricking old players that do not work. But loop does work for only one video now for newer html5 players.

Comment: @VC.One I think you right this look that the playlist made this reload. but the playlist has only one video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u7vq7nImkV8&list=PLMGGIV_q_unoMJGsH4GnoBv2dLkCxdb6D. Look that this is not a bug, to make it loop youtube repeat the playlist and not the video. That look that currently loop work only with paylist so this "lag" is impossible to remove for now.

Comment: @VC.One yeah I have the same video in the same playlist. I did not how to loop without doing that. Any idea how I can loop the video without a playlist?

Comment: @Stargateur Yes Im looping with using the playlist. Any idea how I can loop the video it without the playlist?